# Regarding the series representation of $\sin x \cdot\ln(1+x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

In our calculus textbook, Thomas' Calculus, in Chapter 10.8, we are asked to find the first three nonzero terms of the Taylor approximation of the function $f(x) = \sin(x)\cdot\ln(1+x)$ as well as find its interval of convergence.

In order to do this, I multiplied out the Taylor polynomials:
$$(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...) \cdot (x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...) $$
Then, I distributed the terms of the $\ln(1+x^2)$:
$$x(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...)-\frac{x^2}{2}(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...) + \frac{x^3}{3}(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...) -\ldots $$

Because the problem asked for the first three nonzero terms, I noticed that the first three nonzero terms will be of degree $1,2,$ and $3$. Grouping and distributing these terms, I got the final answer $\boxed{{x^2 - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{6}}}.$ And, since the interval of convergence of $\ln(1+x)$ is $(-1,1]$, the answer only converges for $-1<x\leq1 $.

However, others' methodologies involved multiplying their Maclaurin series representations together and disregarding the summation signs.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

The second series is obtained from shifting the index of the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$. The result they achieved was:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+2}}{(2n+1)!(n+1)} .$$

The teacher agreed with this methodology; however, I had previously thought that one cannot multiply two series and then sum the product of the functions as it is not a property of sums to do so. Furthermore, plugging this series in to WolframAlpha I obtained that this series represents $\frac{2\cosh((x^{3/2}) - 1)}{x}$. And determining the interval of convergence was left as a further exercise outside of class.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Which method was correct in determining and answering the problem?
2. Are there any conditions or situations in which one can multiply two power series in order to determine the Taylor representation of the product of two functions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mind explaining this: And, since the interval of convergence of ln(1+x) is 0, the answer only converges for
x=0

Comment: How do you explain this formula you used: $$(\sum a_n)( \sum   b_n ) =\sum a_n  b_n $$ it is totally wrong

Comment: Have you ever heard about cauchy product? for series?

Comment: @GuyFsone Is the product formula i gave correct?

Comment: @GuyFsone I did not use this formula. Others did and my teacher agreed with this methodology. I thought this was the wrong formula and I multiplied out the Taylor polynomials of both sin(x) and ln(1+x), and I distributed the terms for ln(1+x) to the Taylor polynomial of sin(x) in order to arrive at my answer. I agree with you that this product is totally incorrect.

Comment: @GuyFsone Also, I have now revisited the work and I am mistaken. The interval of convergence for ln(1+x) is (-1,1], my apologies. I will edit the post and correct my work.

Also, I have never heard of the Cauchy product for series.

Answer (score -1):

Your product is incorrect.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i.\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_jx^j=$$
$$\sum_{i,j\ge 0}a_ib_jx^{i+j}=$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl (\sum_{i=0}^na_ib_{n-i}\Bigr)x^n $$

Comment: this is true when at least one of the series is absolutlely continuous. `